# Python Script can't access package or file in /usr/bin

Tags: python, linux, raspbian

In a Python script on Raspbian that I'm developing, I need to reference a file/package that is automatically installed and updated in `/usr/bin`. The Python script runs without sudo in a non-elevated form, and sits within my documents folder. When I try and run the script I receive this error:

> Unexpected error: <class 'PermissionError'>

> Unexpected error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/bin/chromedriver'

I have tried `sudo chmod o+rx /usr/bin/chromedriver` which applied successfully, but this script still has the same error.

The relevant code:

```
driver = uc.Chrome(
                driver_executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver"
            )
```

Is there a way to get this to work? As the package is auto updated in the /usr/bin folder I need to access it in place using a script without elevated privileges.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What exactly does your script do or specifically, what part of the script needs access to /usr/bin?   Please include the relevant code and the full traceback error.  That ```class 'PermissionError``` is strange.

Comment: @ewokx I'm trying to put together a selenium script, which as its launched on a Raspberry Pi requires a specific version of the Chromedriver. The specific code I've now added to the original post. If I copy this Chromedriver binary to a local folder, the script works fine but then if the package updates in the background I'll have to copy it again each time. Hence wanting to access it directly in /usr/bin. Hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think this is reproducible. What happens if you try to run `/usr/bin/chromedriver` from the command line?

Comment: @tripleee if I use the command line it runs fine. I have managed to get it to work if I change the owner/group of chromedriver to my local user. But if I reinstall the package, it goes back to the owner and group of root:root and the script errors again. It seems that the uc package is the one that has the issue with accessing that director. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I don't even know what `uc` is.